# Unable to select all checkboxes using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

I want to select all the items. There should be 50 items on each page. I use the following code:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="results-list-delivery- 
          toolbar"]/div/ul[1]/li[4]/ul/li[3]/button')))
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

I also tried '//input[@type="checkbox" and @data-action="selectall"]' as the xpath. print(element.is_selected()) shows that the checkbox is selected.

The source code of the checkbox is as follows:

```
<li class="hideInMobile has_tooltip checkbox" data-menu="viewtray">
    <span class="hidden">Click to add or remove all documents on the current page to the cart.</span>
    <input type="checkbox" data-action="selectall" aria-label="Select all items on this page">
    <span class="tooltip" role="tooltip">Select all items on this page</span>
</li>
```

Thank you!

It shows 50 SELECTED, but the checkbox is not selected. And if all the items on the page are successfully selected, I can I de-select them after downloading, since I'm going to move to the next page and continue to download for all pages. [image]

[Update]: I can download 50 items by clicking the download button. However, those 50 items are not those 50 that are listed on the page.

Before the Checkall box is clicked:

[image]
After it is clicked: 
    [image]

I can download the items selected. However, they are different from those listed:
    [image]

If successful, it should be like this:
  [image]

Comment: your `element` is not pointing to the checkbox `input` element. It's pointing to the button. Please provide the `li` element code, if you can't resolve after updating the xpath that point to input checkbox.

Comment: updated in the question

Comment: Have you tried doing something with those selected checkbox (remove the entries, mark them as unread)? From my experience, sometimes the checkbox does not appear to be selected, but actions are working on them.

Comment: Open Developer Tools and select Elements tab, focus on checkbox element and confirm it can be visible on the webpage. And check whether the element is in the frame or not.

Comment: @victor, Did you try with the webdriver **click()** method? 
Javascript executor executes a script on background to perform operations, and these operations won't be visible in the UI and if failed won't throw an exception.

Comment: I tried to use the click() method by: browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="results-list-delivery-toolbar"]/div/ul[1]/li[1]/input').click().  Got the error message: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input type="checkbox" data-action="selectall" aria-label="Select all items on this page"> is not clickable at point (408, 241). Other element would receive the click: <div class="box" aria-busy="true" style="vertical-align: middle;">...</div>

Comment: It is not in frames, and it is visible on the page. I tried to click the checkbox before each individual item. Showing some items are selected, but the checkbox is not selected. And the items selected do not match those on the webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could execute javascript to check all the checkboxes.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.execute_script('var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");'
                      'for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {'
                      '  if(checkboxes[i].type == "checkbox") {'
                      '      checkboxes[i].checked = true;  '
                      '   }  '
                      '}')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem has something to do with the accounting setting. By default, only 10 items are displayed on each page. I have an account and changed my default setting to 50 items per page. When I'm logged in with my account, I have this issue. If I don't and use the default 10 items per page, there is no issue.